# Two extended classes - one works and the other doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class

I have had some difficulties in using extended classes in rails, in particular extending the Matrix class - and I have also asked some questions related to this:

[Am I extending this inbuilt ruby class correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070443/am-i-extending-this-inbuilt-ruby-class-correctly)

[Using custom functions in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053203/using-custom-functions-in-rails-app)

[Where do I put this matrix class in my rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052860/where-do-i-put-this-matrix-class-in-my-rails-app)

In general the answers have been around autoloading in rails 3. **However, when I extend 'Math' new functions work, when I extend 'Matrix' new functions don't work - even if I treat them in the same way**

I've tried many iterations and change module names, requires, autoloads but here are my latest key files:

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'matrix'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module SimpleFixed
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # **I have tried all these autoload variants**
    #  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    #  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    #  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
    #  config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
      config.autoload_paths << "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/lib" # <-- set path
      require "extend_matrix" # <-- forcibly load your matrix extension

*other standard code here*
```

lib/extend_math.rb

```
module Math
  class << self

    def cube_it(num)
      num**3
    end

    def add_five(num)
      num+5
    end

  end
end
```

lib/extend_matrix.rb

```
module Extend_matrix **An error is raised if I call this Matrix**

  class Matrix

    def symmetric?
      return false if not square?
      (0 ... row_size).each do |i|
        (0 .. i).each do |j|
          return false if self[i,j] != self[j,i]
        end
      end
      true
    end

    def cholesky_factor
      raise ArgumentError, "must provide symmetric matrix" unless symmetric?
      l = Array.new(row_size) {Array.new(row_size, 0)}
      (0 ... row_size).each do |k|
        (0 ... row_size).each do |i|
          if i == k
            sum = (0 .. k-1).inject(0.0) {|sum, j| sum + l[k][j] ** 2}
            val = Math.sqrt(self[k,k] - sum)
            l[k][k] = val
          elsif i > k
            sum = (0 .. k-1).inject(0.0) {|sum, j| sum + l[i][j] * l[k][j]}
            val = (self[k,i] - sum) / l[k][k]
            l[i][k] = val
          end
        end
      end
      Matrix[*l]
    end

  end

end
```

my view page:

```
<%= Math.add_five(6) %> **works*

<%= Matrix[[25,15,-5],[15,18,0],[-5,0,11]].cholesky_factor %> **doesn't work**
```

Could it be because Math is a Module in ruby but Matrix is a class? If so, how do I correct for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the implementation of `Matrix`, you will see the reason. For me, it is located in `.../ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/matrix.rb`. The definition is (omitted all methods):

```
class Matrix
  include Enumerable
  include ExceptionForMatrix
  ...
end
```

That means that `Matrix` is not contained in a module. Your source for your additions should begin:

```
class Matrix

  def symmetric?
    ...
  end
  def cholesky_factor
    ...
  end
end
```

So your addition to a class or module has to match the current definition. `Matrix` is known as `Matrix` in the Ruby constants, and not as `Extend_matrix::Matrix` which is what you have defined.

Comment: Thanks! This has been bothering me for a week, your solution is perfect. I wish I could give you more points.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the feedback, that alone is worth any points you want to give additionally ;-)