# undefined method `build' for Matrix:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, matrix

I have extended the Matrix class in my rails app to add two new methods as described here:

[Two extended classes - one works and the other doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140113/two-extended-classes-one-works-and-the-other-doesnt)

The above methods now work fine. Also some of the existing methods work fine such as

```
Matrix.column_vector([4,5,6])
Matrix.columns([[25, 93], [-1, 66]])
```

but

```
Matrix.build(2, 4) {|row, col| col - row }
Matrix.build(3) { rand }
```

do not work and give the error

```
undefined method `build' for Matrix:Class
```

The methods are all defined in this page here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-build

What could be causing the build method to not work, when other Matrix methods do work? Am I missing an extra library or class?

EDIT 1: I realised it is because I have ruby 1.8.7 when the build method is defined in 1.9.3

Comment: So write an answer, and accept that later to close your question. The solution is obvious: Switch to Ruby 1.9.3 (or copy the new code into your library, and remember later to remove it again).

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours unfortunately

Comment: But an answer is allowed immediately...

Comment: A user with less than 100 reptuation can't post an answer to their own question for 8 hours (I've already tried)

Answer (score 0):

I realised it is because I have ruby 1.8.7 when the build method is defined in 1.9.3